# Sphinx - Specific file documentation with autosummary

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autosummary

I'm trying to use Sphinx's autosummary extension to generate the documentation automatically for the methods of a single file. I have the following folder structure on sphinx

```
-docs
  -source
    -api.rst
    -conf.py
-src
  -players
    -a.py
    -b.py
```

My api.rst is as follows

```
API
===

A
-
Description of file A
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   src.players.a

B
-
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   src.players.b
```

Where in file `a.py` and `b.py` I have a class with some methods documented using docstring.

What I would like is to see the class and its methods' documentation under each corresponding section, but I cannot make it work.

In my `conf.py` file I have added the following:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

But it does not generate the documentation. I have also tried to include in the path the `src/players` folders, but no luck either.

In general, which is the preferred way to tell Sphinx where to find the code to be documented?

EDIT: The error it throws is the following

```
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: api.rst, index.rst, usage.rst
WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import src.players.a.
Possible hints:
* AttributeError: module 'src.players' has no attribute 'a'
* PycodeError: no source found for module 'src'
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings or error messages?

Comment: @mzjn I edited original question, sorry for not posting earlier.

Comment: Do you have empty `__init__.py` files in each of your package's directories and subdirectories?